# Target Container is not a DOM Element in jest test

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

So I spent last two days looking thorugh similar questions, however, the provided anwsers did not help. I have a web app written in react and want to add unit tests using jest and enzyme. The app is working fine but when I tried to run a simple test it threw an error `Target Container is not a DOM Element.` As far as I understand the test breaks down on the import of index.tsx because the error happens even with an otherwise empty test file.
index.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import store from "./store/createStore";

ReactDOM.render( // this part is giving the error
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

test.tsx - this part is enough to break the test

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import './enzyme.config.tsx';
import '../index.tsx';
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the test file?

Comment: I did not include it because even empty test caused an error so I guessed it's an import problem

Comment: Where is the setupTests file? Did you look into the docs?